# how to use post variable before submit button

Tags: php, variables, post, get

If I given `isset() undefined` error problem solved. but after submit the selected values not displayed. without `isset()` of how to use `$_GET['ddlpub']` in php 7.2.18. it is working in php 5.2.3

```
<select name="ddlpublisher" id="ddlpub" class="ddltxt" >
           <option value="%">--ALL--</option>
           <?php 
           include('dbconfig.php');
           $query = "Select distinct pub from jd order by pub";
           $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
                 if($row['pub']== isset($_GET['ddlpub'])) 
                 {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['pub']. '" selected="selected">'.$row['pub']. '</option>'; 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      echo '<option value="'.$row['pub']. '">'.$row['pub']. '</option>'; 
                 }
           }
           ?>        
       </select>
```

Comment: use  as `if( isset($_GET['ddlpub']) && $row['pub']== $_GET['ddlpub'])`

Comment: i found same thing.. thanks

Comment: great, you can use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$_GET` not `post`.

Also you have to check that `$_GET['ddlpub']` is set and then you have to compare it as below

```
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
                 if( isset($_GET['ddlpub']) && $row['pub'] == $_GET['ddlpub']) 
                 {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['pub']. '" selected="selected">'.$row['pub']. '</option>'; 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      echo '<option value="'.$row['pub']. '">'.$row['pub']. '</option>'; 
                 }
           }
```